# How link 2 layout with a Button

Tags: android

I don't speak english very well, so please try to understand me.
iìm trying to develop a little app for android in eclipse. I've create 2 layout where, in first there are a button and in a second there is only the text "helloword". I want that the button to send me at the "helloworld" layout 
I followed a tutorial but it's not correct.
Someone can help me posting th code to implement??
Excuse my English still 
and thanks for any help

Comment: i think that you and Google are not friends

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two different Activities, with separate layouts. You set their layouts using setContentView inside onCreate. Don't forget to include your activities in the manifest (eclipse generated one for you. follow how it was done in the first activity and you should be fine. no need to add the filters and such, just the .Activity)

then in your first activity's button, do this:

```
my_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MySecondActivity.class);
    startActivty(i);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use just 1 activity then use the following code,

```
my_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        FirstActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);
    }
});
```

Comment: ahhh ok i think that each layout need an activity, now it's clear

Answer (score 1):

Its not so hard just do this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View args0) {
    setContentView(R.layout.aardelayout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just a simple Search on google and you find your answer .
see this tutorials ( two are in frensh if you are prefering frensh tutorials )  :

[tuto1](http://www.tutomobile.fr/intent-passer-dune-activity-a-une-autre-tutoriel-android-n%C2%B011/16/07/2010/)

[tuto2](http://www.android-pour-les-nuls.fr/tutoriaux/developpement/1831-tuto-developpement-android-intent-passer-dune-activity-a-une-autre)

[tuto3](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/03/tutorial-how-to-start-a-new-activity/)

Comment: =) i'm an italian boy but don't worrie. i can undestand, my problem is the explanation!! thanks all very much

Comment: all that is explained on the tutorials from A to Z . welcome Italian , i'm from morocoo ^^